# How to use if statement inside the helper in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I use if statement inside the helper. I have pasted the function from the helper which is not working but I can't find the problem.

helper.php

```
function get_recipients($data)
   {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $CI->load->database();

      $CI->db->where('company_id', $data["company_id"]);

      if ($data["database_name"] != '' || $data["database_name"] != 'all') {
        $CI->db->where('database_name', $data["database_name"]);
      }

      if ($data["province"] != '' || $data["province"] != 'all') {
        $CI->db->where('province', $data["province"]);
      }

      if ($data["district"] != '' || $data["district"] != 'all') {
        $CI->db->where('district', $data["district"]);
      }

      if ($data["ward"] != '' || $data["ward"] != '0' || $data["ward"] != 'all') {
        $CI->db->where('ward', $data["ward"]);
      }

      if ($data["farm"] != '' || $data["farm"] != 'all') {
        $CI->db->where('farming_type', $data["farm"]);
      }

      if ($data["commodity"] != '' || $data["commodity"] != 'all') {
        $CI->db->where('commodity', $data["commodity"]);
      }

      $query = $CI->db->get('addressbook');

      if($query->num_rows() >= 0){
         return $query->num_rows();
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }

   }
```

The values of database, province, district, ward, farm and commodity are either empty, string(all) or any other different string. The WHERE query is to be executed when the conditions match.

The variable $data is coming with the correct data but the WHERE queries are being executed no matter the values of $data

Comment: what is output on `print_r($data)`?

Comment: The output are the values from the form post

Comment: they are coming as strings

Comment: can you post your string format?

Comment: they must be in array fromat.

Comment: this is the result of print_r($data)

Comment: array(7) { ["company_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["province"]=> string(19) "Mashonaland Central" ["database_name"]=> string(9) "section 2" ["district"]=> string(12) "Harare North" ["ward"]=> string(2) "15" ["farm"]=> string(10) "Hotculture" ["commodity"]=> string(7) "poultry" }

Comment: @BrightonMadire what this part do in your code `$CI->db->where('company_id', $data["company_id"]);`

Comment: it select rows where column(company_id) is equal to $data["company_id"])

Comment: Did you try changing all OR conditions to AND ?

Comment: @BrightonMadire from DB ?

Comment: its either empty string or "all"

Comment: with that data what are you trying to do. its juts db code, and can't find where else you used it

Comment: I'm trying to get number of rows (return $query->num_rows();)

Comment: Is this came  `$data["database_name"] ` from DB or from `..recipients($data)` ??

Comment: I have realize if I remove ||(OR) the code will work. Like this -> if ($data["database_name"] != 'all') { $CI->db->where('database_name', $data["database_name"]); }

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
function get_recipients($response)
   {
      $data  = (array)$response;//converts in to array
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $CI->load->database();
      $CI->db->where('company_id', $data["company_id"]);

          if ($data["database_name"] != '' || $data["database_name"] != 'all') {
            $CI->db->where('database_name', $data["database_name"]);
          }

         //more code
```

Comment: Still not working, the result is the same as from my first code